# Spring Boot Test seems to be creating H2 Test DB different than what I would expect

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

So, I have a Test annotated with `@DataJpaTest` and `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)`, and an application.yml under /src/test/resources with this block (yes, indenting should be fine):

```
spring:
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:h2:mem:foobar;MODE=Mysql;MVCC=FALSE;
    username: sa
    password:
    driver-class-name: org.h2.Driver
```

When I start the Test, I unexpectedly get these lines in the log:

```
2019-10-23 17:11:08.311  INFO 13468 --- [           main] beddedDataSourceBeanFactoryPostProcessor : Replacing 'dataSource' DataSource bean with embedded version
2019-10-23 17:11:08.801  INFO 13468 --- [           main] o.s.j.d.e.EmbeddedDatabaseFactory        : Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:7855270f-61b7-4f37-8796-cbfeb8ad42ea;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false', username='sa'
```

In particular this: `Starting embedded database: url='jdbc:h2:mem:7855270f-61b7-4f37-8796-cbfeb8ad42ea;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1;DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=false`

Why is Spring boot starting a DB with a UUID-Generated DB and not taking the settings from spring.datasource.url?

The "productive" app takes the datasource settings fine from the file in /src/main/resources with same syntax without issues...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the documentation of [@DataJpaTest](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/orm/jpa/DataJpaTest.html) you can see that:

> @DataJpaTest uses an embedded in-memory
>   database (replacing any explicit or usually auto-configured
>   DataSource). The @AutoConfigureTestDatabase annotation can be used to
>   override these settings.

So @DataJpaTest annotated with `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` that causes `TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration` to create embedded datasource with hard-coded `generateUniqueName(true)`:

**TestDatabaseAutoConfiguration.java** :

```
EmbeddedDatabase getEmbeddedDatabase() {
    ...
    return new EmbeddedDatabaseBuilder()
        .generateUniqueName(true)
        .setType(connection.getType())
        .build();
}
```

I think they do this to prevent DB name collisions and state mix between test runs.

Comment: Yep, that seems fair enough. However, this way they prevent stuff like `MODE=Mysql;MVCC=FALSE;` from being propagated. In my specific case, it means the DB won't work if you use stuff like pessimistic locking... I managed to get around the issue by using the Annotation `AutoConfigureTestDatabase(Replace.NONE)`. However, it would have been great to ALLOW Spring to do the magic, but with certain config parameters... ;)